# Yii2 - terminate App from event handler after triggering

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-user

I'm using [yii2-user](https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user) for user registration. I want to check whether the user is registered on not before logging in from social account(s). I'm triggering event before creating his account and handling it in the `main.php` globally.

If user is already registered, I want to display some message and not let him continue with registration/login process thereafter.

In short I want the user to get redirected to home page, displaying the message from the event handler if the specified condition is matched.

```
'modules' => [
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
        'enableRegistration' => true,
        'controllerMap' => [
            'security' => [
                'class' => \dektrium\user\controllers\SecurityController::className(),
                'on ' . \dektrium\user\controllers\SecurityController::EVENT_BEFORE_CREATE_ACCOUNT => function ($e) {

                    $email = $e->client->email;

                    $user_model = \dektrium\user\models\User::findOne(['email' => $email]);

                    if($user_model == Null)
                    {
                        return;     //then just return and continue next steps
                    }
                    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('info', "You cannot directly login with this account. Please login with the credentials sent to your email ($email) first and then connect your Account from Settings.");
                    //---------- NOW REDIRECT TO HOME PAGE--------
                }
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

What's the best way to redirect user to home page and stopping execution of current controller?

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
//---------- NOW REDIRECT TO HOME PAGE--------
Yii::$app->response->redirect(Url::home());
Yii::$app->end();
```